# Why is there value error when running keras.fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to train AI to play breakout but when I do `DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=True, verbose=1)` following error happens:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Convolution2D

env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5', render_mode='rgb_array')
height, width, channels = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

episodes = 10
for episode in range(1, episodes + 1):
    env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0

def buildModel(height, width, channels, actions):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, (8, 8), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(3,height, width, channels)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

def buildAgent(model, actions):
    policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=1., value_min=.1, value_test=.2, nb_steps=10000)
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=1000, window_length=3)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                   enable_dueling_network=True, dueling_type='avg',
                   nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=1000)
    return dqn


model = buildModel(height, width, channels, actions)

DQN = buildAgent(model, actions)
DQN.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), metrics=['mae'])
DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=True, verbose=1)

scores = DQN.test(env, nb_episodes=1000, visualize=True)
print(np.mean(scores.history['episode_reward']))
```

I use

- tensorflow: 2.8.0
- keras=rl2: 1.0.4

Full error:

````
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/breakoutAI/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=True, verbose=1)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\breakoutAI\venv\lib\site-packages\rl\core.py", line 182, in fit
    if not np.isreal(value):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```
````

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: @ForceBru, sorry, I forgot to add that

Comment: @Graverman: Change input shape from `input_shape=(3,height, width, channels)` to `input_shape=(height, width, channels)` and if the error still exists, please share the shape of your data.

Comment: @Kaveh shape of my input is observation space is (210, 160, 3). Whem I do i``nput_shape=(height, width, channels)`` I get error: ``ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3, 210, 160, 3)``

Comment: It says the shape of your input data is (1,3,210,160,3) and it expects a shape of (batch_size, 210,160,3). So, check your code to find this mismatch.

Comment: @Kaveh I look but can't find a mismatch, do you see it?

Answer (score 0):

I having the same problem.

I don't know why, but use **render_mode="human"** solve my problem

```
env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5', render_mode='human')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).